# Python script 500 error

Tags: python, cgi

I am currently trying to run a fairly basic python script on my web server. I've gotten this same error when I try to import something that isn't installed on the server so like

`import json`

I've ran a basic script on the server before so I know that python can run on it. The script is working in my python IDE without any problems but when I put it into my server, I get a 500 error. Any ideas as to why this is occuring would be much appreciated. My webhost is JustHost.com and it uses the CPanel. I did contact them and they said it was something about my script.

```
#! /usr/bin/python



import MySQLdb


db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "username","password","database")
CUR = db.cursor()

def get_password(username):
    sql = "select Password from Users where Username=%s"
    CUR.execute(sql, [username])
    result = CUR.fetchone()[0]
    if result == None:
        return "User does not exist"
    else:
        return result[0]

def get_comment(username):
    sql = "select Comments from Users where Username=%s"
    CUR.execute(sql, [username])
    result = CUR.fetchone()
    if result == None:
        return "User has not updated comment"
    else:
        return result[0]

def get_email(username):
    sql = "select Email from Users where Username=%s"
    CUR.execute(sql, [username])
    result = CUR.fetchone()
    if result == None:
        return "User does not exist"
    else:
        return result[0]

def get_longitude(username):
    sql = "select Longitude from Users where Username=%s"
    CUR.execute(sql, [username])
    result = CUR.fetchone()
    if result == None:
        return "User did not update location"
    else:
        return result[0]

def get_latitude(username):
    sql = "select Latitude from Users where Username=%s"
    CUR.execute(sql, [username])
    result = CUR.fetchone()
    if result == None:
        return "User did not update location"
    else:
        return result[0]

def get_address(username):
    sql = "select Address from Users where Username=%s"
    CUR.execute(sql, [username])
    result = CUR.fetchone()
    if result == None:
        return "User did not update email"
    else:
        return result[0]

def friends_list(username):
    sql = "select all friend from accepted_req where userLoggedIn=%s"
    CUR.execute(sql, [username])
    result=[]
    query = CUR.fetchall()
    if query == None:
        return "User has no friends"
    else:
        for friend in query:
            result.append(friend[0])

    return result

def markers_on_map(username):
    friendsList = friends_list(username)
    fullFriendsList = []
    for friend in friendsList:
        UserDictionary = {}
        UserDictionary["Username"] = friend
        UserDictionary["Comment"] = str(get_comment(friend))
        UserDictionary["Latitude"] = get_latitude(friend)
        UserDictionary["Longitiude"] = get_longitude(friend)
        fullFriendsList.append(UserDictionary)

    return fullFriendsList


print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"

print markers_on_map("brock")
```

Comment: Have you checked that the environment variables are set when the script is started from the webserver? Depending on how `MySQLdb` is installed, `$PYTHONPATH` may be your friend...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by making it looks exactly perfect in standards of my webhost. the new script now looks like this

```
#! /usr/bin/python



import MySQLdb


db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "username","password","database")
CUR = db.cursor()

def get_password(username):
    sql = "select Password from Users where Username=%s"
    CUR.execute(sql, [username])
    result = CUR.fetchone()[0]
    if result == None:
        return "User does not exist"
    else:
        return result[0]

def get_comment(username):
    sql = "select Comments from Users where Username=%s"
    CUR.execute(sql, [username])
    result = CUR.fetchone()
    if result == None:
        return "User has not updated comment"
    else:
        return result[0]

def get_email(username):
    sql = "select Email from Users where Username=%s"
    CUR.execute(sql, [username])
    result = CUR.fetchone()
    if result == None:
        return "User does not exist"
    else:
        return result[0]

def get_longitude(username):
    sql = "select Longitude from Users where Username=%s"
    CUR.execute(sql, [username])
    result = CUR.fetchone()
    if result == None:
        return "User did not update location"
    else:
        return result[0]

def get_latitude(username):
    sql = "select Latitude from Users where Username=%s"
    CUR.execute(sql, [username])
    result = CUR.fetchone()
    if result == None:
        return "User did not update location"
    else:
        return result[0]

def get_address(username):
    sql = "select Address from Users where Username=%s"
    CUR.execute(sql, [username])
    result = CUR.fetchone()
    if result == None:
        return "User did not update email"
    else:
        return result[0]

def friends_list(username):
    sql = "select all friend from accepted_req where userLoggedIn=%s"
    CUR.execute(sql, [username])
    result=[]
    query = CUR.fetchall()
    if query == None:
        return "User has no friends"
    else:
        for friend in query:
            result.append(friend[0])

    return result

def markers_on_map(username):
    friendsList = friends_list(username)
    fullFriendsList = []
    for friend in friendsList:
        UserDictionary123 = {}
        UserDictionary123["Username"] = friend
        UserDictionary123["Comment"] = str(get_comment(friend))
        UserDictionary123["Latitude"] = get_latitude(friend)
        UserDictionary123["Longitiude"] = get_longitude(friend)
        fullFriendsList.append(UserDictionary123)

    return fullFriendsList
```